# How to set up osqa at webfaction

Tags: webfaction, osqa

requirements.txt file:

django>=1.1
mysql-python
python-openid
psycopg2
html5lib
markdown
git+git://github.com/dcramer/django-sphinx.git
South

first, virtualenv ~/webapps/ --distribute
source ~/webapps//bin/activate
export PATH=/usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/:$PATH (this is to avoid the pg_config not found error 
http://community.webfaction.com/questions/736/installing-psycopg2)
then
pip-2.7 install -r requirements.txt

And remember don't do pip install which install into 2.4; need to invoke pip-2.7 install

Comment: self answered above.
Other reqource include
http://wiki.osqa.net/display/docs/Installing+OSQA+on+WebFaction which can help set wsgi files.

Comment: This was helpful too http://meta.osqa.net/questions/10897/has-anyone-installed-osqa-on-heroku

Comment: http://docs.webfaction.com/software/custom.html

Answer (score 3):

1. Go [here](https://wiki.webfaction.com/wiki/InstallScripts#OSQA).
2. Click "Install".
3. Add the OSQA app that you just created to your site.
4. Done!

Comment: That script does not work for me. Do you know of any other methods?

Comment: If the script is failing, then figure out the reason for the failure and correct it. Let WebFaction's support team know if you need assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Just to share, I installed OSQA on Webfaction following SeanF's instructions above and it was a breeze.  I could even customize the script a little bit.  Now the work is on customizing the site, not spending countless setting up the deployment.  Thanks Webfaction and SeanF.